# Saving CryptoJS's CryptoMD5 state as a string and restoring it later

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I gradually compute the MD5 hash of a large file, during an upload, then at some point I want to save to HTML5 `localStorage` what I have calculated so far, to be able to resume later.

From what I know, `localStorage` can store strings, so I have to store the progressive MD5 value as a string and then restore them, when the user opens the browser at a later time.

Basically my code looks like this:

```
var md5_full = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();

var wordArray = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.create(chunk);

md5_full.update(wordArray);
```

At this point, I want to convert `md5_full` to a string, to be able to save to `localStorage`. And then, at a later time, when the user wants to resume the upload, to be able to retrieve the `md5_full` from `localStorage`, unstringify, and continue to update it with chunks.

In the end I should be able to call `md5_full.finalize();` to get the final full MD5 hash digest.

Comment: I'm trying to use https://github.com/hunterloftis/cryo (CryoJs) to stringify and then parse back. But the update() method for example, it's not present in the object, but rather I have to call md5_full.$super.$super.update() ... so CryptoJS is using some inheritance mechanism that is not restored properly

Comment: The code for stringify and parsing back is: md5_full_str = Cryo.stringify(md5_full); md5_full_restored = Cryo.parse(md5_full_str); Then, md5_full_restored.update() is not available as described above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem may be with function serialization - CryoJS apparently attempts to serialize functions but it may not restore references correctly (the scope is lost).

The code below circumvents this problem by restoring only data, not functions. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RC3Vv/).

(De)serialization functions:

```
/** Serialize MD5 object. */
function stringify_md5(md5) {
    return JSON.stringify(md5);
}

/** Deserialize MD5 object. */
function parse_md5(serialized_md5) {
    var md5 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();
    restore_data(JSON.parse(serialized_md5), md5);
    return md5;    
}

/** Recursively copy properties from object source to object target. */
function restore_data(source, target) {
    for (var prop in source) {
        var value = source[prop];
        if (typeof value == "object") {
            if (typeof target[prop] != "object") {
                target[prop] = {};
            }
            restore_data(source[prop], target[prop]);
        } else {
            target[prop] = source[prop];
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
var chunk1 = "abc", chunk2 = "def";

// The correct hash:
var md5_full_1 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();
md5_full_1.update(chunk1);
md5_full_1.update(chunk2);
var correct_hash = md5_full_1.finalize();

// Using stringify/parse
var md5_full_2 = CryptoJS.algo.MD5.create();
md5_full_2.update(chunk1);
var md5_serialized = stringify_md5(md5_full_2); // serialize
md5_full_2 = parse_md5(md5_serialized);  // deserialize
md5_full_2.update(chunk2);
var result_hash = md5_full_2.finalize();

alert(correct_hash.toString() == result_hash.toString()); // true
```

(*Using WordArray threw me an error in CryptoJS for some reason*)